# Can wildcard SSL certificates be used with PHP imap_open?

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, imap, imap-open

I am using PHP's `imap_open` function to connect to an IMAP email server.  This has been working fine for several years, but the email server was recently changed and I have started getting the following error:

> "Cannot connect to mail server: Certificate failure for
>   subdomain.mail.domain.com: Unable to locate common name in
>   certificate"

The email server's tech support responded:

> "The common name for our cert is "*.mail.domain.com". As it is a wildcard certificate, there is no explicit hostname for it. It appears that your scripts are expecting the certificate to return explicitly for "subdomain.mail.domain.com" when our wildcard certificate will not. This is why the error above occurs."

If I disable SSL certificate checking using the `/novalidate-cert` flag in the `imap_open` function I'm able to connect, but I'd obviously prefer to keep certificate validation enabled.  Is there a way to do this with wildcard certificates and the `imap_open` function?

Comment: Are those hostnames correct? Are you really trying to connect to `subdomain.mail.domain.com` or is that just a stand-in example name?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, that's a stand-in example name.